# React Routing vs Express Routing

Tags: node.js, express, react-router

Been watching alot of tutorials and i see that there is express routing as well as react routing.

Is the react routing for client and the node js routing for server (api?).

Wanting to know if someone could please clarify this as new to React, Node, Express.

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

It is possible (and even recommended) to **use both of them in combination**.

### TL;DR

- `react-router` is used to navigate between multiples **pages** of your **front-end** app or website, usually in a single page app (SPA), where pages are loaded dynamically (not all the page is reloaded).
- `express` router is a way to **return static content** (index.html, image.png...) AND to **handle API calls** that are often related to database logic. Those routes are handled **server-side**.

### Example

`myapp.com/my-portfolio` is a **view** and should be handled and rendered by **react router**

```
// this router render pages components dynamically based on the url
<Route path="/my-portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
<Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
```

`POST myapp.com/api/user/create` or `GET myapp.com/api/getMyJson` is an **api call** that should be handled server-side by the **express router**:

```js
// this api call returns database content as json
app.get('/api/user/:userId', async (req, res) => {
  const user = await database.user.getById(req.params.userId)
  return res.json(user) // the json method set the header so that your frontend can interpret this json correctly
});

// server route that return the content of folder 'app/public' where
// the index.html and static resources are usually exposed
app.use(express.static('app/public'))
```

### Single page application workflow

- The **front-end** (client browser) request the **back-end** (your server) for the application static content (myLogo.png, index.html...) usually served by **express** router
- While the first page is loaded and the user begin to interact with the app, the **front-end** continues to load other pages in the background (lazy loading)
- When the user navigate to another page (with **react-router**), the page is already loaded and the user is taken there without any further server call to get static conent nor page reloading
- While using the app, the front-end request data or services on demand via api routes that are handled by express on the server side (for example when a user click the notification icon, the server is requested to get the last N notifications for the user to be displayed in the dropdown menu)

Answer (score 13):

I'll try explain the difference through an example. Say we have a single page application built with react at www.example.com

React Routing

We hit www.example.com and the index.html is loaded from the server. Note that it has all of your react pages in your bundle.js file. You now click the about button on the navbar, this sends you to www.example.com/about. This call does not hit the server, it is handled by your react router.

Express

Much like above we hit www.example.com and get the index. This time when we hit /about we get information from the server

Take a look at this blog post:https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/isomorphic-javascript-the-future-of-web-apps-10882b7a2ebc

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. However, I ran into a strange problem. My app is working fine except recently I try to add social login. I can login in my localhost, but in production mode, It seems it can't get to my express route '/api/auth/google', instead the browser stays at http://example.com/api/auth/google. So, react is not forwarding this route to express (or express is not getting it before react?). In client I use <a href="/api/auth/google"....I have looked everywhere but got no clue. Can you give me a hint what it might be?